# How to add new property to already existing json object

Tags: javascript, json

I have already existing object

```
var info = {fname: '', lname: ''}
```

I want to add new property type: 'abc' to info , so that the final result will  be

```
{fname: '', lname: '', type: 'abc'}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var info = {fname: '', lname: ''}
info.type = 'abc';
console.log(info);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the new property to object as info.type = 'abc';
[image]

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution is:

```
var info = {fname: '', lname: ''};

info = {...info, ...{type: 'abc'}};
```

Or with Object.assign:

```
var result = Object.assign(info, {type: 'abc'});
```

> { fname: '', lname: '', type: 'abc' }

Answer (score -1):

Simple as this:

```
var info = {fname: '', lname: ''}
info['type'] = 'abc';
```

More about JSON objects:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp